# Twitter Sentimental Analysis with twitteR, all scores are zero?

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm new to Twitter Sentimental Analysis with twitteR, and used the positive.txt and negative.txt from Hu and Liu. I was so glad that everything ran smoothly but the scores for over 1000 tweets all turned out to be neutral (score = 0)? I can't figure out what went wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret)

    #Get tweets about "House of Cards", due to the limitation, we'll set n=1500
    netflix.tweets<- searchTwitter("#HouseofCards",n=1500)
    tweet=netflix.tweets[[1]]
    tweet$getScreenName()
    tweet$getText()
    netflix.text=laply(netflix.tweets,function(t)t$getText())
    head(netflix.text) 
    write(netflix.text, "HouseofCards_Tweets.txt", ncolumns = 1)

    #loaded the positive and negative.txt from Hu and Liu
    positive <- scan("/users/xxx/desktop/positive_words.txt", what = character(), comment.char = ";")
    negative <- scan("/users/xxx/desktop/negative_words.txt", what = character(), comment.char = ";")

    #add positive words 
    pos.words =c(positive,"miss","Congratulations","approve","watching","enlightening","killing","solid")

    scoredsentiment <- function(hoc.vec, pos.word, neagtive)
    {
        clean <- gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "",hoc.vec)
        clean <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", clean) 
        clean <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", clean)
        clean <- gsub("[^[:graph:]]", "", clean)
        clean <- gsub("[[:cntrl:]]", "", clean)
        clean <- gsub("@\\w+", "", clean)
        clean <- gsub("\\d+", "", clean) 
        clean <- tolower(clean)

        hoc.list <- strsplit(clean, "") 
        hoc=unlist(hoc.list)

        pos.matches = match(hoc, pos.words)
        scoredpositive <- sapply(hoc.list, function(x) sum(!is.na(match(pos.matches, positive))))  
        scorednegative <- sapply(hoc.list, function(x) sum(!is.na(match(x, negative))))
        hoc.df <- data.frame(score = scoredpositive - scorednegative, message = hoc.vec, stringsAsFactors = F)
        return (hoc.df)
    }

    twitter_scores <- scoredsentiment(netflix.text, scoredpositive, scorednegative)
    print(twitter_scores)
    write.csv(twitter_scores, file=paste('twitter_scores.csv'), row.names=TRUE)

    #draw a graph to show the final outcome
    hist(twitter_scores$score)
    qplot(twitter_scores$score)
```

Everything works, but the score for each tweet is the same (score =0)

Comment: Everything works, except it doesn't work.... got it. Where are `scoredpositive` and `scorednegative` defined outside of the function so you can use them as inputs to the function? I suspect if you ran this code on a clean environment (restart R), that it wouldn't "work" any more.

Comment: @cory LOL I definitely have more work on my use of lanaguge haha it actually ran through it again after I restarted R, but still I only got score = 0 for all the tweets

Comment: `scoredpositive` and `scorednegative` are not defined in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Cognitive Services for calculation of the Sentiments Score. 
Microsoft Cognitive Services (Text Analytics API) API can detect sentiment, key phrases, topics, and language from your text.

Refer this link to use Microsoft Cognitive Services in R [link](https://bigdataenthusiast.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/microsoft-cognitive-services-text-analytics-api-in-r/)

For [Sentimental Analysis in R](https://bigdataenthusiast.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/sentimental-analysis-in-r/)

Comment: While this may be a useful service, suggesting that he change completely the service/tool he is using really doesn't answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I don't think that the simple match will work. You need to use some form of fuzzy matching scheme. With match, you need the exact word repeated which will not happen a lot and further, you are matching a single word to a string of words.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you elaborate? Thanks so much!

Comment: well, that is where you need to do the research. You can look at the various string distance measures or using gsub. There are a lot of resources out there. But if you have to ask for elaboration on a simple task, maybe you should spend more time on researching your project before you go into it head first.